# How can I forbid import specific modules in python script

Tags: python, linux, module

There is a python interpreter on my platform, and other people can write a python script running on it. I don't want them to use some module to change the system, for example sys, os and so on; how could I control this?

Comment: Delete the modules from where they are located...

Comment: Delete the os and sys modules?

Comment: what do you mean 'change the system'? usually this kind of security is handled with users/groups and permissions. if you remove `os` and `shutil` someone who can log to your system can still just use `rm` (assuming the platform is *nix) to remove files he/she has the permissions to...

Comment: You cannot achieve what you want just by forbidding them to use specified modules as they can use several different way to accomplish the same goals. What you really should do is creating limited user which has no privilege to change system for them.

Comment: Thank you! I agree your view, we suppose the system can't be write directly, but you can write the python script on phone and download to platform. You can use some module I supported.If I can check the keywords in it when others running a script？

Comment: Now I creare a sanbox environment and run it,Thank U